# Android Kotlin - Socket Server to handle Multiple Clients

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin

I am creating a Socket music game using Kotlin in android, right now I have a 1 on 1 functioning app that does all I want it to, but I want to be able to support multiple clients(4 max), how should I refactor my code to do this? , should I be using coroutines or Threads? , the server sends a song to each client every 30 seconds so I would ideally like a way to send the same message to each client with minor delay

**Server**

```
                    val server = ServerSocket(6000)
                    Log.i("Server","Opening Connection on ${server.localPort}")
                    val client = server.accept()
                    Log.i("Server","Client Connected")
                    output = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
                    var input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.inputStream))


                    output.println(j_song.toString())

                   
                    // Sending each song in a playlist to all clients
                    for(i in songs)
                    {
                        val send_song = Gson().toJson(i)
                        output.println(send_song)
                        val status = input.readLine()
                         // Other functionality

                        }
```

**Client**

```
GlobalScope.launch {
           socket = Socket("10.0.2.2", 5000)
           output = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)
           input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
           Log.i("Client Connected", "Connected to Server ${socket.inetAddress.hostAddress}")
           val mes = input.readLine()
           Log.i("Client", mes)

           val songs = JSONArray(mes)
           Log.i("Client (JSON LIST)", songs.toString())

         
           
           var server_song : String
           while(true)
           {

                server_song = input.readLine()
                output.println(status)
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `val client = server.accept()` After that statement you should start a thread that handles that client. Then call accept() again in a loop. The output and input variables should be private to the client thread.

Comment: Thank you for your help, is their a way that I can access the output and input variables from the server to write to each client?

Comment: I do not understand your question. The server creates a thread for every client. And for every client there is an input and an output private for the thread. The only one that uses the outputs and inputs is the server. Who else? Put all the code after server.accept() in the thread for the clients.

Comment: `Log.i("Server","Opening Connection on ${server.localPort}")` Wrong message. A server cannot start a connection. A server starts listening for a client to connect.

Comment: Sorry what am I asking is that is each client delegated to a different thread with its own instance of input and output variables? , thanks for letting me know !